# SQL Server Lock Pages in Memory

Tags: sql-server

Does SQL Server 2012 x64 standard edition running on Windows 2008 R2 has LPIM (Lock pages in memory turn on by default -- out of the box)? If not does this should be needed to be turn on?

Comment: Whether any given setting should be on or not almost always depends on your particular circumstances.

Comment: Not always true. Instant file initialization should be ON

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally SQL Server is not allowed to lock pages.  You have to grant rights "lock pages in memory" using [the policy editor "gpedit.msc"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190730.aspx).

If it has the rights, SQL Server 2012 [will use it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178067.aspx):

> The SQL Server Lock Pages in Memory option is set to ON in 32-bit and
>   64-bit instances of SQL Server 2012 Standard edition and higher when
>   the account with privileges to run sqlservr.exe has been granted the
>   Windows "Locked Pages in Memory” (LPIM) user right

Comment: add if sql service is running (a bad practice) as local admin or domain admin account LPIM is implictly granted. correct me?

Comment: By default not even administrators have the LPIM right.  You have to grant it manually  if SQL Server runs as local admin.

Comment: per this link it should be on for administrators http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqldatabaseengine/thread/6583a6ba-9ff6-4de9-af0e-3a64df6f9e9b